# Is it allowed to use Apples own app icons inside our app?

Tags: ios

As the title suggests, can we use Apples app icon for i.e. the Camera Album app in our own app? Can't seem to find any related information in the Apple Human interface guidelines.

This is how we will display it:

[image]

Comment: I would worry more about copyrights than human interface guidelines

Comment: the answers you will get here will either be link-only and therefore discouraged or irrelevant since they are no official apple doc / legal statement.

Comment: We use the Apple Health logo in our app when we ask for Health Kit permission similar to what you're doing here. The app is approved and it's been on the store for over a year. That being said this is just anecdotal evidence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no place for legal advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / intellectual properties / copyright / legal issues instead of directly about programming. **[See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From  https://www.apple.com/uk/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html

> You may not use the Apple Logo or any other Apple-owned graphic
>   symbol, logo, or icon on or in connection with web sites, products,
>   packaging, manuals, promotional/advertising materials, or for any
>   other purpose except pursuant to an express written trademark license
>   from Apple, such as a reseller agreement.

Comment: This may be only for use outside of iOS apps, as I have seen a few people use Apple's app icons (but not the Apple logo).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. I am using Siri shortcut logo and apple wallet logo in my app.

Comment: "I did not get caught so it is fine" is not sound legal advice.